# Changing month to different language in laravel with timesamps

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, locale

I am trying to change/format `created_at` and `updated_at` fields created by laravel when timestamps are set to true in its model.

suppose if the value is '2016-10-08' i want it to change as '2016-أكتوبر-08'

Is there a way to customise the way they are stored in the database.

I 've tried setting the locale in app.php,

```
'locale' => 'ar',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this Eloquent Mutator to your model to override the base model using your set locale value (*`ar` as defined in your `app.php`*):

```
protected function asDateTime($value)
{
    return (parent::asDateTime($value))->setLocale(App::getLocale());
}
```

Comment: When i tried above code , it pops up with an error :::::  Class 'App\App' not found 
and if i add :: use App;  it shows another error ::::::: Call to a member function format() on null